# How to fix an error in a Deno dependency?

Tags: dependencies, deno

I'm trying to use a program using deno, with the following code:

```
deno run -A --unstable --no-check https://github.com/langwitch-tools/langwitch-deno/raw/main/src/configs/interactive.ts
```

but an error comes:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Deno.setRaw is not a function
      (Deno.setRaw as setRaw)(
                             ^
    at Select.#readChar (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_prompt.ts:299:30)
    at Select.#readKey (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_prompt.ts:287:50)
    at Select.read (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_prompt.ts:181:57)
    at Select.read (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_list.ts:254:18)
    at Select.#execute (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_prompt.ts:113:21)
    at async Select.prompt (https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/prompt/_generic_prompt.ts:92:14)
    at async https://raw.githubusercontent.com/langwitch-tools/langwitch-deno/main/src/configs/interactive.ts:28:12
```

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

`setRaw` was moved from the `Deno` namespace to `Deno.stdin` in Deno v `1.26.0`. See the [documentation](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable@v1.26.0/%7E/Deno.stdin), [release notes](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.26.0#:%7E:text=Deno.setRaw), and [blog post](https://deno.com/blog/v1.26#unstable-denostdinsetraw-api).

From the blog post:

> In this release, the unstable `Deno.setRaw(rid)` API has been removed in favor of `Deno.stdin.setRaw()`. We plan to stabilize this API in the next minor release.

---

In the specific scenario you gave (in which you're trying to run a script that uses dependencies that you don't control, and one of those dependencies uses the outdated API): it might be possible to use an updated version of the specific dependency causing the issue by using an [import map](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.2/linking_to_external_code/import_maps).

It appears that the dependency which uses the no-longer-existing API ([`cliffy`](https://deno.land/x/cliffy)) was [updated](https://github.com/c4spar/deno-cliffy/pull/459) to fix the issue.

Here's an import map which maps the version of cliffy used by [the version of the script at its latest commit](https://github.com/langwitch-tools/langwitch-deno/blob/c4667e3b24f2aea5b974cb28d027871decb8b48b/src/configs/interactive.ts#L11) to the latest version of cliffy at the time I write this:

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.24.2/": "https://deno.land/x/cliffy@v0.25.2/"
  }
}
```

When I run that version of the script in Deno v`1.26.2` with the import map, it appears to work (I stopped the process after seeing the first question):

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.26.2 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.7.193.16
typescript 4.8.3

% deno run --allow-all --unstable --import-map=import_map.json 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/langwitch-tools/langwitch-deno/c4667e3b24f2aea5b974cb28d027871decb8b48b/src/configs/interactive.ts'
```

```txt
 ? ✦ please pick a language (˶ᵔ ᵕ ᵔ˶) if you don't know, try esperanto first!
 ❯ ar -> Arabic
   hy -> Armenian
   as -> Assamese
   ay -> Aymara
   az -> Azerbaijani
   bm -> Bambara
   eu -> Basque
   be -> Belarusian
   bn -> Bengali
   bho -> Bhojpuri
```